# How to save a value correctly to userdefaults?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an issue and I hope that I will find the answer here to my questions. I made a Circular Timer, but everytime I'm closing the view , is going back from the start.

I tried to save the value where the time is calculated "onTick", is working for 2-3 seconds, and after again is going back from the start and is countdown from there.

I'll put a picture/video bellow with the behaviour, maybe somone can help me fix it .

Thanks !

This is WaitingOrderView.

```
struct WaitingOrderView: View {
    @State private var timer: AnyCancellable?
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if syncViewModel._order.id == 0 && syncViewModel._order.status == 0 {
                 CartView()
             }
           else  if syncViewModel._order.status == syncViewModel.statusList.first(where: { status in
                status.key == StatusKey.accepted.rawValue
            })?.id
            {
                OrderConfirmedView()
            }
       
            }
        .onAppear() {
            startFetchStatus()
        }
        }

    func startFetchStatus() {
        timer = Timer.publish(every: 20, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink { _ in
                syncViewModel.fetchOrder(id: syncViewModel._order.id)
            }
    }
    }
```

The function startFetchStatus() gets the data from the backend every 20 seconds, and it looks like this, for example: [Fetch response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxIfL.png)

This is the CircularTimer View  :

```
let timer = Timer
    .publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
@available(iOS 15, *)
struct CircularTimer: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    @State var orderDate : Date
    @State  var orderDeliveryDate : Date
    @State var onTick: Double = 1
    @State var savedOnTick : Double = 1
    let date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing : 0){
            Image("clock_button")
            ZStack{
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle().stroke(Color.gray.opacity(22/100), lineWidth: 5)
                )
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle().trim(from:0, to: onTick)
                            .stroke(
                                style: StrokeStyle(
                                    lineWidth: 5,
                                    lineCap: .round ,
                                    lineJoin:.round
                                )
                            )
                            .foregroundColor(
                                ( completed() ?  Color.orange : Color.orange)
                            ).animation(
                                .easeInOut(duration: 0.2)
                            )
                    )
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
                Image("indicator_ellipse")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 230, height: 230)
            }
            .onAppear {
               getData()
                print(savedOnTick)
            }

            .onDisappear {
               saveData()

            }
        }
       
        .onReceive(timer) { time in
            progress(time: Int(time.timeIntervalSince1970))
              
        }
    }
    func completed() -> Bool {
        return onTick == 1
    }
    func progress(time: Int)  {

        let minutesOrderDeliveryDate = Int(orderDeliveryDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
        let minutesOrderDate = Int(orderDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
        let minutesCurrentDate = time
        
        let totalMinutes =  minutesOrderDeliveryDate - minutesOrderDate
        let remainingMinutes = minutesOrderDeliveryDate - minutesCurrentDate
        onTick =  CGFloat(remainingMinutes) / CGFloat(totalMinutes)

        
    }
    func dateFormatTime(date : String) -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return dateFormatter.date(from: date) ?? Date()
    }
    
    
    func saveData() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(onTick, forKey: "onTick")
    }
    
    
    func getData() {
       onTick = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "onTick")
    }
}
```

This is OrderConfirmedView :

```
struct OrderConfirmedVieww: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    @State var nowDate: Date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(Texts.orderConfirmedText1)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundColor(.colorGrayDark)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(3)
                .padding(40)
            CircularTimer(orderDate: dateFormatTime(date: syncViewModel._order.date ?? ""), orderDeliveryDate: dateFormatTime(date: syncViewModel._order.deliveryDate ?? ""))
                .padding()
//            Spacer()
            Text(Texts.orderOraLivrareText)
                .font(.headline)
                .fontWeight(.thin)
                .padding(.bottom)
            Text(dateFormatTime(date: syncViewModel._order.deliveryDate ?? ""), style: .time)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Text(Texts.orderButtonText)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(height: 55)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.onboardingColor)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    func dateFormatTime(date : String) -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
        return dateFormatter.date(from: date) ?? Date.now
    }
    
}
```

[image: Video]

Comment: `completed() ? Color.orange : Color.orange` doesn't make any sense. Why not simply `.orange`?

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, edited now. What about my problem ? :D

Comment: the proper way to use UserDefaults in SwiftUI is @AppStorage  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper

Comment: use @AppStorage("onTick") var onTick: Double = 1

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed tried it right now, still the same behaviour :(

Comment: issue is how you get the value from appstorage i think